# Im developing a laravel website and when i deployed on server im getting this database error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin, cpanel

[This is the error imp getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHBPb.png)

this is the url of the site http://graphixvilla.com/login

Comment: this is a simple error that says that the `footer.blade.php` file does not exist in layout folder.

Comment: This is not a database error. Error itself shows it clearly

Answer (score 0):

On **Linux**, the file system is **case sensitive**.

Actually your error message is accurate

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
View [layout.footer] not found. (View: /home/stsgcc25/myapp1/myapp1/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

And lucky you, ignition tells you that you have a typo in your file name (`Did you mean layout.Footer?`)

It must be **F**ooter instead of **f**ooter